# what events are used in symbian c++ to catch the notifications sent by the service provider

Tags: events, notifications, symbian

I know the title isn't that clear so let me try to explain using an example. Say, when we send a message through my phone, we immediately recieve the balance deduction notification from our service provider. My question is that which event is used to catch this notification in symbian C++.

Could we possibly change the way notifications are displayed?? Say for eg., nokia symbian 60 phones show these notifications as a pop-up where some phones use the entire screen to show the deducted amount. Can I catch this event and show it in the form of a new message ?? I mean to say that the balance deduction notification is shown as a message in my phone's inbox but not as a mere pop-up and then lost.

Thanks in advance.

Regards,
Avanish

P.S. Please try to advice as soon as possible. I would highly appreciate your responses as they will help me in deciding the strategy for my application. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking about the messages that appear on the screen on a phone when used with Pay As You Go SIM showing the balance.  This may depend on the service provider but usually, the message notifications are Class 0 SMS messages (also known as Flash SMS).

[Class 0 SMS](http://www.ozekisms.com/index.php?owpn=544) are defined as:

> Class 0 SMS: This message is displayed on the mobile phone immediately and a message delivery report is sent back to the SC. The message does not have to be saved in the mobile phone or on the SIM card (unless selected to do so by the mobile user). This type is also referred to as Flash SMS.

Therefore, you can catch these notifications by monitoring for these types of incoming SMS (assuming the SDK allows this).